# Word cloud not displaying correctly with d3.v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-cloud

I'm trying out this [example](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) of an animated word cloud, using [jasondavies's d3.layout.cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud).

It works with d3 version 3, but if you update it with any version above it won't display correctly. You can still see the transition of some words but the others remain in the middle with no scaling.

[image]

I'm putting the code here as reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <!--script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script-->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
  <script>

//Simple animated example of d3-cloud - https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud
//Based on https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/simple.html

// Encapsulate the word cloud functionality
function wordCloud(selector) {

    //var fill = d3.scale.category20();

    //Construct the word cloud's SVG element
    var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
        .attr("width", 500)
        .attr("height", 500)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(250,250)");


    //Draw the word cloud
    function draw(words) {
        var cloud = svg.selectAll("g text")
                        .data(words, function(d) { return d.text; })

        //Entering words
        cloud.enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });

        //Entering and existing words
        cloud
            .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

        //Exiting words
        cloud.exit()
            .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
                .attr('font-size', 1)
                .remove();
    }


    //Use the module pattern to encapsulate the visualisation code. We'll
    // expose only the parts that need to be public.
    return {

        //Recompute the word cloud for a new set of words. This method will
        // asycnhronously call draw when the layout has been computed.
        //The outside world will need to call this function, so make it part
        // of the wordCloud return value.
        update: function(words) {
            d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500])
                .words(words)
                .padding(5)
                .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
                .font("Impact")
                .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
                .on("end", draw)
                .start();
        }
    }

}

//Some sample data - http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Opening_lines
var words = [
    "You don't know about me without you have read a book called The Adventures of Tom Sawyer but that ain't no matter.",
    "The boy with fair hair lowered himself down the last few feet of rock and began to pick his way toward the lagoon.",
    "When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced that he would shortly be celebrating his eleventy-first birthday with a party of special magnificence, there was much talk and excitement in Hobbiton.",
    "It was inevitable: the scent of bitter almonds always reminded him of the fate of unrequited love."
]

//Prepare one of the sample sentences by removing punctuation,
// creating an array of words and computing a random size attribute.
function getWords(i) {
    return words[i]
            .replace(/[!\.,:;\?]/g, '')
            .split(' ')
            .map(function(d) {
                return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 60};
            })
}

//This method tells the word cloud to redraw with a new set of words.
//In reality the new words would probably come from a server request,
// user input or some other source.
function showNewWords(vis, i) {
    i = i || 0;

    vis.update(getWords(i ++ % words.length))
    setTimeout(function() { showNewWords(vis, i + 1)}, 2000)
}

//Create a new instance of the word cloud visualisation.
var myWordCloud = wordCloud('body');

//Start cycling through the demo data
showNewWords(myWordCloud);


</script>
```

Note: I edited the fill color from the example to be black. If you want to use the original color palette in d3 v4 or above, you need to use `var fill = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I did some digging, they basically merged the enter and update function into one using `merge` starting from version v4.

So for the above to work, you have to replace

```
//Entering words
        cloud.enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; });

        //Entering and existing words
        cloud
            .transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```

with

```
//Entering words
        cloud.enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("font-family", "Impact")
            .style("fill", "black")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('font-size', 1)
            .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
            //Entering and existing
            .merge(cloud).transition()
                .duration(600)
                .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);
```